# Terraform kubernetes_namespace tries to connect locally when cluster is not created

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

I am having a module called kubernetes for creating kubernetes cluster, and my main main.ft file contain below code:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.kubernetes.kubeConfig.0.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(module.kubernetes.kubeConfig.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(module.kubernetes.kubeConfig.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.kubernetes.kubeConfig.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  
}
```

i have created another module called kube_config

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "namespace" {
  count = length(var.env)
  metadata {
    name = "test${var.env[count.index]}"
  }

}
```

When use apply I am getting below error since cluster is not created.

```
Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/xxxxx/secrets/xxxxxx": dial tcp [::1]:80: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

it's trying to connect locally. but if cluster is already created the above issue wont be there.

kindly help

Comment: You simply can't use the kubernetes provider in the same module that create the cluster because TF provider information is determined on `terraform init`, before anything exists. I would recommend splitting the cluster creation and anything that needs to k8s provider into separate modules.

Comment: yes, provider is in main module

Comment: The last version of the Kubernetes provider that would allow you to do something like this is 2.3.2. Is that version compatible with your config?

Comment: 2.11.0 is the version being used